# How to set jquery global value

Tags: jquery

I have select box as

```
<select id='selectboxID'>
  <option value="">select id</option>
  <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
  <option value="Child artist">Child artist</option>
  <option value="">Musician</option>
</select>
```

My jquery code

```
$(function() {
   var option = 80;
   $("#selectboxID").change(function() { 
       option = 17;

  });
alert(option);
})
```

My requirement is  When I select any option then option variable value should be 17 .Please advise how to do.

Comment: what is the purpose of `alert` outside the change handler

Comment: What's not working for you? Your code looks fine. Your alert will obviously be `80` when you run the code because the event hasn't fired yet and the handler hasn't been called.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. You might want the `alert` in the change function or the alert won't happen when you change the select.

Comment: yes I want to alert when I select any value from select box

Comment: Okay! You are alerting the option value, when doc gets ready but you don't have any alert in change handler it never alerts anything.

Answer (score 1):

Move the global variable outside of the function

```
var option = 80;
$(function() {   
   $("#selectboxID").change(function() { 
       option = 17;
       alert(option);
  });    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(function() { })` statement says that you hare writing handler of the `document.ready` event. So all variables declared inside of this block will be visible only inside of this block. You just need to move out of your block your variable declaration:

```
var option;
$(function() {
   option = 80;
   $("#selectboxID").change(function() { 
       option = 17;

   });
   alert(option);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an alert inside change event:

```
$(function() {
   var option = 80;
   $("#selectboxID").change(function() { 
     option = 17;
  }).change();  //<---------change like this
  alert(option);
});
```

[See this in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/AGc5G/)

Comment: Its ok , But actually I want to use option value outside

Comment: Could you plz tell the purpose of it.

Comment: when I select child artist then  

     slider range should be 1 to 17
     else slider range should be 1 to 80

Comment: @Bhaveshvaghela just updated the answer. you need to apply change event on ready.

Comment: I am using range slide for age range

Comment: yes I have seen update answer , it is giving alert only on  page load  , it is fine but when i click or select option then it should be alert means it should give value on change select box

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside the function and inside the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     var option=80;//Global Declaration
     $(function() {
        $("#selectboxID").change(function() { 
            option = 17;
         });
         alert(option);
     });
</script>
```

Next time when u will call the function you will get the previous value assigned to `option` variable

Answer (score 0):

Your scope of the alert and the `option` value checking is not correct, try like this:

```
$(function () {

    // Check option value on load
    var option = 80;
    alert(option);

    $("#selectboxID").change(function () {
        option = 17;
        // check the option on dropdown onchange event
        alert(option);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NX3Wr/)